# How to build Qt-5 application in Windows with no dependencies

Tags: c, windows, qt

I'd like to know the definitive method of building a Qt 5 application on Windows such that no dependencies whatsoever are required to run it, in particular the C runtime. I want to be able to distribute the final .exe with no prerequisite software/DLLs required. In particular, I want to avoid requiring my users to have to install vcredist.exe for MSVC*.dll or the MinGW redistributables.

I'll happily use either of the compilation environments (MinGW or MSVC), and will rebuild Qt from source if that is a necessary step (though I'd like to know if it is indeed necessary).

Comment: I just supply all of the dependencies in an NSIS based installer that I make for my application. It was a bit of work to setup but once you have generation of an installer working its no work to generate a new installer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to static build the code. Chech this link explaining step by step method to build your code statically. http://qt-project.org/wiki/How-to-build-a-static-Qt-for-Windows-MinGW#9731f56412bd237286d3271405d55fd2